# Include authorization header in email

Tags: c#, rest, email, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I have a rest API on azure, secured with B2C authentication. The thing is that some of the recipients of a certain email who will need to confirm or deny an appointment are not registered users. I would like to give them a link they can click that will set a particualr meeting in the database to have their response - but they wouldnt have authentication to use the API.

My initial thought was to create some api put endpoints that would just modify the response value - but again, they wont have access to the API.

Is it possible to generate auth codes manually for any user? Or make a dev user that has authentication, and steal a code from it to include in the email header somehow?

What are the best practices here

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599732/azure-b2c-one-time-access-to-secured-api/64600820#64600820) resolves your query.?

Comment: Hi @aescript can you please let us know if you are still looking for help on this

Answer (score 1):

You can give them password which will expire in 24 hours or one time password or include one time encrypted token (best option) in the link in an email

Comment: How would I do that in Azure b2c

Comment: You are sending an email to users who are not registered users through SMTP. In that email body, you provide the link with token encrypted.  When  they click on the link, they come to your site and your application decrypt and validate the token and present the options to confirm or deny an appointment or select alternative date for an appointment

Comment: Again, this unfortunately isn't helpful. You are telling me to send them to a link with a token i can decrypt - thats the workflow of the problem im describing. Im asking how I would implement this when the only place i have to give URLs to requires authorization.

Comment: You can create token in many ways.  Token could be GUID and can kept in database and valid for one day or few hours or one time use only with time limit.  You can send an email from  API to customer through SMTP.  This email body can have link to your site and that link will also have encrypted key using which you will authenticate the customer.  Now how to send the email from Azure , please see this article - https://blog.mailtrap.io/azure-send-email/

Comment: But again... this is the problem. I cannot put it in the database, as they cannot ACCESS the database. it requires authentication. You keep glossing over the thing i have no idea how to do "jsut send an enxrypted key" lol. I have no idea how to get a key that i can put into a URL that will allow authentication to my API using azure