# Azure B2C One time access to secured API

Tags: c#, azure, email, azure-ad-b2c, one-time-password

I have a web app (rest API) on azure, and I have a B2C setup that is securing it, requiring you to be signed in to access the API. This is good, as i wanted the API to be restricted to members. Basically, the entire web app requires authentication, and will prompt you for a sign in.

Heres the problem - my app has users (who have accounts) and clients (who do not have accounts). These clients might receive an email about a new appointment being set up with one of the users - this email should have one or more links/buttons (ie, a button to Confirm appointment, one to Decline, and one to request a reschdeule) and upon clicking this link I would like to update a field in my database via the rest api, so the USER knows the CLIENT's response. The trouble is, since the client wont have an account, I have no idea how I can give them a link they would be allowed to go to, and have the update happen.

I have tried to do a bunch of research - ive looked into AD external identities with a one time passcode - but i cant seem to find any info on how i would actually get this to work for my purposes.

Does anyone know how I might implement this in azure? Is there a way to call to azure form c# to generate a one time authentication that i can encode into a URL or something?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming I understood, do all the endpoints of the API have to be authenticated? _Typically_ there is a "sign up/login" resource that is "public" (in a web app). The _assumption_ here is that the client's response (confirm,decline,propose) doesn't _require_ privileged access.

Comment: I dont really know how to acheive that using azure b2c to secure the api - it kind of just secures the entire web app.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an anonymous authentication by using a magic link. The users account won’t even need to live in the directory. The link can be short lived, and potentially one time use. We call it id_token_hint or a magic link.

Sample here
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

And reference here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint